# jQuery UI has no method 'sortable'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

My playlist plug-in with jQuery UI works fine alone, but when I include it on the index page, it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable'  /868
```

[Here is my index page at Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JDJPkdgH)

[My page's link](http://duudey.com/index.php)

Comment: Are you sure your jquery-ui has sortable function included?

Comment: In your pastebin you're including jQuery 5 times... and not including jQueryUI at all. In your page's link, you're including jQueryUI 3 times and jQuery multiple times also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

That's a relative path, so while js/jquery-ui.min.js might point to the right place in the first location, if there isn't a similar file there in the second location you're going to get the problem you see (ie. no jQuery UI).

Comment: Just noticed that in your working (ie. non-index) page you *don't* have a relative URL; you have `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged all my js includes and put them to the top of the index.php. Now it's working...